# How can I call a non static method into a static method in php?

Tags: php, behat

I completely new to PHP. I have done something this:

```
 class Foo  
 {         
    @BeforeSuite
    public static function prePare()
   {           
       $obj = new Foo;
       $obj->iVisit("https://google.com");
     }
  }

 public function iVisit($url)
   {
      if ($url != null) {
            $this -> getSession() -> visit($url);
         }
      else {
           throw new PendingException();
         }
   }
}
```

But it is throwing this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getSession() on a non-object

Edited:

My scenario is to load a URL before other test cases start to run. So I choose to load the url in the `@beforesuite` function, but in behat, `@beforesuite` is a static function. I had to call the iVisit method from the static function.

Is there any other solution for this problem?

Comment: Show us code where you are using this class.

Comment: I don't see a getSession() method anywhere in your class not to mention iVisit is not inside the Foo class. Also why in god's name are you instantiating your class inside itself?  @Lenap void you say...the Java part of SO is that way ===^

Comment: @Andrei P I have to call the non static method from a static method . So i did that , if it is wrong , could you please tell me the solution

Answer (score 2):

Its not a php concept, its just a programming concept.

You cannot just call a *non static method* anywhere, simply because you need to make an *instance* (or refer to a already present *instance*) of that *class* to call the function.